# PHP Zip 3 small text files and force download

Tags: php, zip, stream

My website writes 3 small text files based on users information and then presents these 3 files as links that they must "right click" and save to their desktop.

I would like to keep that, but also somehow offer a way to zip these 3 small files up and force download.  And I don't want to save the zip file on the server either.  Can this be done and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

For the forced download you need to send out the file headers first.

```
header('content-type: application/zip');
header('content-disposition: inline; filename=YOUR_ZIP_FILE_NAME_HERE.ZIP"');
```

For zipping you'll wanna use one PHP's zip libraries, then echo/output the zipped content.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Something like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
//the string "file1" is the name we're assigning the file in the archive
$zip->addFile(file_get_contents($filepath1), 'file1'); //file 1 that you want compressed
$zip->addFile(file_get_contents($filepath2), 'file2'); //file 2 that you want compressed
$zip->addFile(file_get_contents($filepath3), 'file3'); //file 3 that you want compressed
echo $zip->file(); //this sends the compressed archive to the output buffer instead of writing it to a file.
```

Comment: is there a way to actually create the zipped file "on the fly" without actually creating and saving the zip file?

or does the above accomplish this?

Comment: This example does that..  it doesn't save the file, it just keeps it in memory before echoing it. "file1", "file2", and "file3" are the the files you asked to have compressed.