# Manipulate an Archive in memory with PHP (without creating a temporary file on disk)

Tags: php, memory, archive, disk

I am trying to generate an archive on-the-fly in PHP and send it to the user immediately (without saving it). I figured that there would be no need to create a file on disk as the data I'm sending isn't persistent anyway, however, upon searching the web, I couldn't find out how. I also don't care about the file format.

So, the question is:

Is it possible to create and manipulate a file archive in memory within a php script without creating a tempfile along the way?

Comment: Can this archive contain only one file or more than one file?

Comment: In my specific case it contains more than one.
Also I'd think that a solution for "arbitrarily" large archives (item-wise) is much more interesting (in my case, I can use a tempfile, but what about people that have to use a server where their access to the filesystem is restricted)?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had the same problem but finally found a somewhat obscure solution and decided to share it here.

I came accross the great `zip.lib.php`/`unzip.lib.php` scripts which come with `phpmyadmin` and are located in the "libraries" directory.

Using `zip.lib.php` worked as a charm for me:

```
require_once(LIBS_DIR . 'zip.lib.php');

... 

//create the zip
$zip = new zipfile();

//add files to the zip, passing file contents, not actual files
$zip->addFile($file_content, $file_name);

...

//prepare the proper content type
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_archive.zip");
header("Content-Description: Files of an applicant");

//get the zip content and send it back to the browser
echo $zip->file();
```

This script allows downloading of a zip, without the need of having the files as real files or saving the zip itself as a file.

It is a shame that this functionality is not part of a more generic PHP library.

Here is a link to the `zip.lib.php` file from the phpmyadmin source:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/RELEASE_4_5_5_1/libraries/zip.lib.php

**UPDATE:**
Make sure you remove the following check from the beginning of zip.lib.php as otherwise the script just terminates:

```
if (! defined('PHPMYADMIN')) {
    exit;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This code is available on the CodeIgniter project as well:
https://github.com/patricksavalle/CodeIgniter/blob/439ac3a87a448ae6c2cbae0890c9f672efcae32d/system/helpers/zip_helper.php

Comment: You should mention that you need to modify it to remove the check for the definition of the 'PHPMYADMIN' constant, or it will just end the script. Took me more than a second to work that out.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the check was introduced after I posted the above answer. I updated the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. I made this into a Codeigniter helper with no problems at all.

Comment: I created a Codeigniter helper with this code. Works for me. Here it is: https://github.com/patricksavalle/CodeIgniter/blob/439ac3a87a448ae6c2cbae0890c9f672efcae32d/system/helpers/zip_helper.php

Comment: @nettle looks like the file was moved to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/ZipFile.php

Comment: link is 404 now on github

Comment: Thanks, fixed the link.

Answer (score 3):

what are you using to generate the archive? You might be able to use the stream php://temp or php://memory to read and write to/from the archive.

See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: At the moment, I'm using the php zip extension and writing a tempfile whenever I serve a download.

I tried using the php://temp wrapper (figuring that it was superior to php://memory, as with large quantities of data, a tempfile IS a good idea, and hosts might allow its use even while restricting fs access.

I ran into the problem that I had to close the zipfile, which appearantly freed everything in php://temp/ . (Reading from the zipfile before and after closing gave me 0 bytes.)

Anyway, I don't care about the library I use, as long as it works. PHP-internal would be preferred, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your comment that php://temp works for you except when you close it, try keeping it open, flushing the output, then rewind it back to 0 and read it.

Look here for more examples: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php

Also research output buffering and capturing: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ZipArchive::addFromString` - if you use `addFile()` the file is not actually added until you go to close it. (Horrible bug IMHO, what if you are trying to move files into a zip and you delete them before you close the zip...)
The `addFromString()` method adds it to the archive immediately.

Answer (score -7):

Is there really a performance issue here, or does it just offend your sense of rightness?  A lot of processes write temporary files and delete them, and often they never hit the disk due to caching.

A tempfile is automatically deleted when closed. That's it's nature.

There are only two ways I can think of to create a zip file in memory and serve it and both are probably more trouble than they are worth.

- use a ram disk.
- modify the ziparchive class to add a method that does everything the close() method does, **except** actually close the file. (Or add a leave-open parameter to close()).
  This might not even be possible depending on the underlying C libraries.