# How to create a zip file in temp memory, not in my hosting using php then download?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a zip file. But I don't create any file in my hosting. I want to create a zip file virtually (i.e. Temp Memory) then it's to be download. How I will do this process with PHP?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) in the PHP docs? creating the file in the php://output stream?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulate an Archive in memory with PHP (without creating a temporary file on disk)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189019/manipulate-an-archive-in-memory-with-php-without-creating-a-temporary-file-on-d)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [nettle that answered this in a previoues question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189019/manipulate-an-archive-in-memory-with-php-without-creating-a-temporary-file-on-d)

> I had the same problem but finally found a somewhat obscure solution
>   and decided to share it here.
>
> I came accross the great zip.lib.php/unzip.lib.php scripts which come
>   with phpmyadmin and are located in the "libraries" directory.
>
> Using zip.lib.php worked as a charm for me:

```
require_once(LIBS_DIR . 'zip.lib.php');

... 

//create the zip $zip = new zipfile();

//add files to the zip, passing file contents, not actual files
$zip->addFile($file_content, $file_name);

...

//prepare the proper content type header("Content-type:
application/octet-stream"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=my_archive.zip"); header("Content-Description: Files of an
applicant");

//get the zip content and send it back to the browser echo
$zip->file();
```

> This script allows downloading of a zip, without the
>   need of having the files as real files or saving the zip itself as a
>   file.
>
> It is a shame that this functionality is not part of a more generic
>   PHP library.
>
> Here is a link to the zip.lib.php file from the phpmyadmin source:
>   https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/zip.lib.php
>
> Make sure you remove the following check from the beginning of
>   zip.lib.php as otherwise the script just terminates:

```
    if (! defined('PHPMYADMIN')) {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If you believe this question is a duplicate (and it probably is) a good approach is just to add a comment to that effect under the question. Higher-rep users will see that, and may cast a close vote.

Comment: Oh my bad i am sorry, will keep this in mind in the future, thank you for poining it out.