# How to convert a byte array to file in php?

Tags: php, file, arrays

How can I convert a `byte array` of zip folder including image files to `zip folder` in `php` ? I can't find the solution so please help me..

This is my `byte array` and my code..

```
$photoObject ="504b 0304 1400 0000 0000 818a d944 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0b00 0000 4e65
7720 666f 6c64 6572 2f50 4b03 0414 0000
0008 006b 9085 44c9 0419 fceb 5001 008c
6c01 002b 0000 004e 6577 2066 6f6c 6465
722f 7363 7265 656e 7368 6f74 202d 2074
7265 6174 6d65 6e74 6f70 7469 6f6e 2e50
4e47 945a 6750 935d 168e 652d 6b41 41e9
45a5 8934 41e9 1054 a423 7c80 80d4 2845";

$hex         = preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/','',$photoObject);
$binary      = pack("H*", $hex);
$photoObject = base64_decode($binary);
$im          = imagecreatefromstring($binary);

$photoName   = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_' , "zipname");

if ($im !== false) {
    $filedb = '../zipper/'.time().$photoName;
    imagepng($im, $filedb);
    imagedestroy($im);
    return $filedb;
}
else {
    return "error";
}
```

Comment: which kind of file do you mean? images, ...

Comment: Could you show an example how your `bytearray` looks?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9648562/1922137

Answer (score 0):

If your string is the valid representation of your archive, php has the means to convert it back to a regular file/binary string.

```
<?php

$bString = hex2bin($hex);

file_put_contents('new_zip_path', $bString);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('new_zip_path', ...);

$image = $zip->getFromName('my.jpg');
```