# Create a Zip from file streams in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I have created multiple PDF file streams in memory. Can I create a zip file from these streams, and if so how? I want to give the user a downloaded zip of my files without creating any files on the server.

[ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) only appears to take file names when running `addFile`.

Comment: sounds like you want https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9648562/1889470):

Similar to the solution given there, I used the class from [phpmyadmin](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/RELEASE_4_5_5_1/libraries/zip.lib.php) as follows:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='whatever.zip'");

$zip = new ZipFile;
foreach($pdfs as $idx => $content) {
    $zip->addFile($content, "file$idx.pdf");
}
file_put_contents("php://output", $zip->file());
```