# Does PHP's tmpfile() typically create the file in memory or on disk?

Tags: php, file

I was curious about the behavior of `tmpfile()` and whether or not invoking it like

```
$temp = tmpfile();
```

Would create a file on disk or in memory. Perhaps it depends on the underlying system? In that case, is there a "more-often-than-not" case where most systems use one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) implies that it would be created on disk, and specifically says to look for details in your system's implementation of `tmpfile(3)`.

[tmpfile(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html) (on Linux) says Glibc will try the path prefix `P_tmpdir` defined in stdio.h, and if that fails the directory `/tmp`.

If you're looking for an in-memory temp file, perhaps you want [php://temp](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).