# How do you zip 3 small text files and force download with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zip

Is there a Zend Framework method to save content from 3 files (be they dynamically generated or actually exist) and force download as a file?

Similar to this question (which didn't work for me when running from inside a controller so far, despite trying a few different ways):

[PHP Zip 3 small text files and force download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953996/php-zip-3-small-text-files-and-force-download)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PHP ZIP library (you need to have that preinstalled) like that:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) !== true){
    throw new Exception('Could not create zip file ' . $filename);
    die('zip fail');
}else{
    $zip->addFile($file1Uri, 'file1.txt');
    $zip->addFile($file2Uri, 'file2.txt');
}

$zip->close();

if(file_exists($filename)){
    return true;            
}else{
    throw new Exception('Could not create zip file ' . $filename);
}
```

Deliver the ZIP file:

```
protected function _deliver($file, $name, $extension, $size, $mime){
    header('Pragma: private');
    header("Expires: -1");
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); 
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Type: " . $mime);
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '.' . $extension . '"');
    header("Content-Length: " . $size);
    set_time_limit(0);        
    if(!readfile($file)){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the upvoted one on your other question. Do it from controller, then call `exit` after you output the zip data so don't you render the view.

Comment: I'm getting this error on addFile or addFromString (I've tried both): "Invalid or unitialized Zip object" even though if I do a file_get_contents and echo it out, the data is valid.

Comment: You have to call $zip->open($filename). with a unique filename (maybe the sessionID of theuser). You can't create a zip in memory.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So basically the upvoted answer is wrong? It doesn't have a $zip->open($file) & in the comments says "it just keeps it in memory before echoing it."

Comment: Yes, it is frustrating but i came across the same issue before. It is probably dependent on the php version.

Comment: And maybe windows vs *nix. I'd like it to work in both envs. Going to test it presently.

Comment: That wasn't it. There was a bunch of stuff, I kept throwing different settings, headers, etc and finally got it to work. Whew! Thanks for your help-.